# How to deal with large delays in displaying data in WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, delay

I'm using WPF TreeView to display statistics to the user. The TreeView is bound  to a bunch of objects through MVVM.

Sometimes, when TreeNode does contain a lot of items, it takes several seconds to display all of those. During this time the application appears stuck.

I want for the TreeView to appear responsive during this delay.

If I was doing this in WinForms, I'd display some sort of loading icon, and do the calculation in the background thread, after which I'd update the corresponding TreeNode.

WHat is the best way to deal with this problem in WPF?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use threading so that your application doesn't appear stuck while processing big amounts of data.

Example:

In the application Im developing right now, I need to search through all folders for spesific files. This freezes the application(not even letting me minimize the window) until it has done the entire search.

To avoid this, I use something called BackgroundWorker which instead lets me perform the search in the background. This means that I can still have control of my application while its doing strenuous work in the background.

Backgroundworker also has a WorkerReportsProgress property. With this enabled you can easily update a progressbar or a percentage counter to let the users know what is happening while its doing the work.

Its really well explained in the book Professional C# 4 and .NET 4.
Its published by Wrox.

Comment: He knows how to use threading and clearly states it. He asks about WPF specific solution.

Comment: @Arek My mistake.. I miss read his question. This answer might help others though..

Answer (score 1):

1. Use threads to make UI breath.
2. Load only root nodes of `TreeView` and children only if user requests it, by clicking [+].
3. Use [Data Virtualization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization) to load, so show *only* the data actually visible on UI.

By combining these techniques, even a part if them you alredy will improve perfomance significally.